# Linux C LibPCRE output unique results

Tags: c, regex, pcre

I have the following code that matches a REGEX in a string that contains multiple duplicates, what I want to do is to print out only unique matches, what can I do? Add to an array than make it unique and only then print out the results? Thanks!

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pcre.h>

int main() {
  pcre *myregexp;
  const char *error;
  int erroroffset;
  int offsetcount;
  int offsets[(0+1)*3]; // (max_capturing_groups+1)*3
  const char *result;
  char *subject = "9,5,3,2,5,6,3,2,5,6,3,2,2,2,5,0,5,5,6,6,1,";
  myregexp = pcre_compile("\\d,", PCRE_MULTILINE|PCRE_DOTALL|PCRE_NEWLINE_ANYCRLF, &error, &erroroffset, NULL);

  if (myregexp != NULL) {
    offsetcount = pcre_exec(myregexp, NULL, subject, strlen(subject), 0, 0, offsets, (0+1)*3);

    while (offsetcount > 0) {

      if (pcre_get_substring(subject, offsets, offsetcount, 0, &result) >= 0) {
        printf("%s\n", result);
      }

      offsetcount = pcre_exec(myregexp, NULL, subject, strlen(subject), offsets[1], 0, offsets, (0+1)*3);
    }

  } else {
      printf("Syntax error in REGEX at erroroffset\n");
  }

}
```

This outputs:

```
bash$ ./regex
9,
5,
3,
2,
5,
6,
3,
2,
5,
6,
3,
2,
2,
2,
5,
0,
5,
5,
6,
6,
1,
```

and I need:

```
bash$ ./regex
0,
1,
2,
3,
5,
6,
9,
```

Comment: some whitespace wouldn't hurt readability...

Comment: _"whitespace where"_ <-- lmao... he's talking about indentation, leaving some lines open, adding some comments, so your code is easier to read. basically, he's saying where's the whitespace, too. PS: the string/format seems rather simple, have you considered/tried to do this using `strtok`? it'd be a lot easier, IMO

Comment: Nope, can't use strtok() because the data here is just an example, I need to use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, add to an array and deduplicate from there.

You can not search unique values with regex. You can search replace with regex and deduplicate some things like double new lines, multiple spaces and so on,  but this doesn't work when the deduplication needs to occur using random seeking.

Here is an example of how to `deduplicate: a -> b`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
main()
{
    char *a[5];
    int a_len = 5;

    a[0] = "a";
    a[1] = "b";
    a[2] = "b";
    a[3] = "a";
    a[4] = "c";

    char *b[a_len];
    int b_len = 0;

    int already_exists;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < a_len; i++) 
    {
        already_exists = 0;
        for ( j = 0; j < b_len; j++)
        {
            if (!strcmp(a[i], b[j]))
            {
                already_exists = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!already_exists)
        {
            b[b_len] = a[i];
            b_len++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < b_len; i++) 
    {
        printf("%s", b[i]);
    }
}
```

For these small arrays this is probably the fastest algorithm. For better performance on bigger arrays I would suggest deduplication on a sorted array.

Comment: Add to a dynamic string array then deduplicate after all matches end?

Comment: Sorry to be an a*s, care for a simple example? Tried that and instead array ended with a `pointer to pointer`... I'm still newbie in C, so easier in python, php, ruby with arrays and unique...

Comment: Updated my answer. Just wondering: why aren't you using any of the languages you mentioned?

Comment: Because those are interpreted languages needing interpreter and can't run the scripts on their own :-|

Comment: have a look at pyinstaller.org

Comment: Yes, I know it, used it. Learning some C won't hurt either :)

Comment: Thanks, sorry, didn't :D